# Почему мы пишем «хлебобулочный», но «мясо-молочный, ликеро-водочный»?

Tags: орфография, слитно-дефис, сложные-прилагательные

Интересно, можно ли навести порядок в написании подобных слов, то есть определить для них единую форму письма и объяснить ее. Также можно отметить, что написание двух последних  слов   постоянно меняется, например: Фряновский  мясомолочный комбинат, Гомельская мясо-молочная компания, Златоустовский ликероводочный завод,  Ликёро-водочный завод «Кристалл».

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ 1.

С точки зрения практики.

а)Из форума:Народ, умоляю, срочно: как пишется ХЛЕБОБУЛОЧНЫЙ Через дефис или нет?
Ответ: стопудово слитно, а чё ? домашнее задание делаешь чтоли??) 
б) Грамота.ру дает слитное написание слов "хлебобулочный, лавровишневый, лироэпический.
в) Интересно, как предприятия успевают за Лопатиным исправлять наименования "мясо-молочный и ликеро-водочный". Это же не ручкой править, там все намного сложнее.

С точки зрения конкретного правила.
Равнение на сочинительную и подчинительную связь дает не лучшие результаты. Может быть, там действую другие факторы?

С точки зрения теории.
А с этой точки зрения теории нет никакой. Орфографических принципы выбора формы написания отсутствуют. Неужели нельзя для трех форм написания сочинить их обобщенные значения и ориентироваться на них в каждом случае?

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ 2.

В приведенных словах вступили в противоречие два разных подхода: сочинительная связь основ склоняет нас к дефисному написанию, но в первой основе отсутствует суффикс прилагательного, а это признак слитного написания. 
Мне бы хотелось предложить Лопатину  (а вдруг услышит?) такую схему решения.

1. Определяем  обобщенное значение трех форм написания: слитно пишутся слова, раздельно пишутся словосочетания, дефисная форма является промежуточной (уже не слово, но еще не словосочетание).
2. Для различных ТЕМ  обобщенный принцип выбора дефисной формы КОНКРЕТИЗИРУЕТСЯ. Для сложных прилагательных предлагается такая формулировка: дефисное написание  - это УСЛОВНАЯ (СОКРАЩЕННАЯ) запись двух прилагательных, связанных сочинительной связью (однородной или неоднородно): кисло-сладкий вкус – это кислый и сладкий вкус (однородное сочинение, можно вставить союз И), всемирно-историческое значение – это всемирное историческое значение (неоднородное сочинение, первое слово обычно сужает значение второго).
3. Слово «хлебобулочный» можно рассматривать как сложное слово со слитным написанием (способ образования – чистое сложение, хлеб + О+ булочный), а можно рассматривать как сокращенную запись двух прилагательных:  хлебный и булочный →хлеб(н)о-булочный. Не стоит для всех слов такого вида выбирать единое решение. Можно назначить слитную форму основной (если хотим подчеркнуть близость основ), а дефисную форму считать исключительной (если хотим подчеркнуть независимость основ). В любом случае надо выбрать что-то одно, объяснить свой выбор, зафиксировать его в словаре и оставить слово в покое. "Хлебобулочный, мясомолочный" лучше писать слитно, а англо-русский - раздельно.

Comment: Когда-то у меня была хорошая статья по теме, правда, давно, возможно, устарела. Попытаюсь найти её он-лайновый вариант.

Comment: Ту не нашла, нашла другую, ссылка в ответе.

Answer (score 4):

Навести порядок можно, но вряд ли от нас здесь что-то зависит.   Правило о написании сложных прилагательных находится в процессе становления. Для привычного варианта (если образовано от сочинительного словосочетания, пишем через дефис, если от подчинительного, то слитно)слишком много на практике исключений. Указанные Вами слова в словаре Лопатина пишутся через дефис в соответствии с основным правилом. Или Вы хотите услышать наш вариант правила? Это, пожалуй, тянет, на исследование и требует времени на обдумывание.

---

Нашла статью Б.Букчиной в газете "Русский язык". Суть:

*Основанное на формальном критерии правило звучит так: если первая часть сложного прилагательного – основа прилагательного (формальный признак – наличие суффикса), то сложное прилагательное пишется через дефис. Если первая часть лишена формальных признаков прилагательного (нет суффикса), то сложное прилагательное пишется слитно.Это правило утверждено Орфографической комиссией*

Подробно [здесь](http://rus.1september.ru/article.php?ID=200000701)